# ActiveMQ 5.15 - Change context root of web console

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.15, and I want to add a path-element to the url for the ActiveMQ web console so it works with my nginx-ingress in a k8s cluster

For example it is now `127.0.0.1:8161/admin`, but I want to use `127.0.0.1:8161/activemq/admin/`.

I tried to change the settings in `jetty.xml`, but I couldn't find the correct position for entering a context-root `activemq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

conf/jetty.xml: just edit pathelement to /activemq/admin

```
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <property name="contextPath" value="/activemq/admin" />
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
```

--- ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: activemq
  name: activemq-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

spec:
  rules:
    - host: someip.linode.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /activemq
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: activemq-service
                port: 
                  number: 8161
```

Comment: Don't know about that feature, thank you