# How to change the context path of ActiveMQ Classic's broker endpoint

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to change the URL to access ActiveMQ Broker.

For example:

```
ws://localhost:61614/broker1
```

Where `broker1` is the context path I configured.

I found a way to change the context path of ActiveMQ's web console ([ActiveMQ 5.15 - Change context root of web console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857104/activemq-5-15-change-context-root-of-web-console)), but the broker I couldn't find a way to change the context path itself.

If possible I would like to do this without using a reverse proxy
I would like to achieve this by simply changing ActiveMQ settings.

Is there any other way?

I tried the following.

- Investigation of broker and Jetty documentation (but not found)
- To place nginx in the front of the broker

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question doesn't seem like a good fit for the Developer focused Stackoverflow website, have you considered using one of the sister stackexchange sites https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com for this kind of question about operation or configuration of a server?

Comment: ActiveMQ does not currently support changing the context path. What is the use case in where that would be required? You should be able to put whatever context path you want in the NGINX/Apache/whatever http proxy and map it back-and-forth